# Referencing to class from within method

Tags: javascript, ajax, this

I am working on a script that should be able to dynamically load content in multiple predefined DIVs in the topbar of my webpage.

Within the Topbar Object, Ribbon is an object that holds the functions used to manipulate one of the DIVs in the Topbar, some of which (all at the moment) are inherited from Container, of which Ribbon is an instance.

The functions `MPP_Topbar.Ribbon.clear()` and `MPP_Topbar.Ribbon.load('default.xml')` work as intended. However, the callback function `MPP_Topbar.Ribbon.insert()`, which is called from the `ajaxGet()` function once the xmlhttprequest is completed, does not do what it's supposed to do. Somehow `this` within the `insert` class method suddenly points to `window` instead of its parent object `Ribbon`.

Is there any way for me to reference `Ribbon` within the `insert` method?

---

**The Topbar script:**

```
MPP_Topbar = {};

MPP_Topbar.Container = function(){};

MPP_Topbar.Container.prototype.clear = function(){
    var element = this.element;
    while (element.firstChild) {
        element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
    }
};

MPP_Topbar.Container.prototype.load = function(page){
    this.clear();
    ajaxGet(page, this.insert);
    console.log('loading');
};

MPP_Topbar.Container.prototype.insert = function(content){
    console.log(this);
    this.element.innerHTML = content;
    console.log('inserted');
};

MPP_Topbar.Ribbon = new MPP_Topbar.Container;

MPP_Topbar.Ribbon.element = document.getElementById('THERIBBON');
```

---

**The function used for the AJAX request:**

```
function ajaxGet(file, callback, postdata, async){
    async = ((async == true || async === undefined) ? true : false);
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if(async){
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    if(postdata){
        xmlhttp.open("POST", file, async);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    }else{xmlhttp.open("GET", file, async);}
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a bound version of the "insert" function:

```
ajaxGet(page, this.insert.bind(this));
```

Without that step, the "insert" function will be invoked such that `this` refers to the global (`window`) object. The value of `this` has nothing to do with how or where a function is declared, and everything to do with how the function is *invoked*. The `.bind()` method returns a function that explicitly arranges for `this` to be bound to the object you pass as a parameter when the desired function is called.

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for! I have seen many answers with exorbitant workarounds while this solution is so straightforward. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NotABlueWhale note that `.bind()` isn't available on old (IE) browsers, but [there is a substitute you can use that's almost exactly like the built-in version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility).